# Chromedriver con selenium no funciona crontab

Tags: python, bash, script, cron, virtualenv

Tengo un problema al ejecutar un scrapper que utiliza selenium y chrome-driver, el cual, cuando desde el terminal se llama al script que usa el scrapper, lo hace correctamente. Sin embargo, si este script lo meto en crontab, recibo el siguiente error

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current google-chrome version is 99.0.4844
Get LATEST chromedriver version for 99.0.4844 google-chrome
Driver [/root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/99.0.4844.51/chromedriver] found in cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/laura/Descargas/scrapper2/scrapper.py", line 16, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 269, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 360, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5556a91e07d3 <unknown>
```

Esto, no me sale, cuando intento ejecutarlo sin el crontab, como bien he dicho antes
La configuración y los comandos que tengo tanto en el crontab como en el script que llama al scrapper en python, son los siguientes
También tengo que decir, que hago esto tanto con el crontab -e, como con sudo crontab -e, por si hay algun problema.

Mis permisos en los archivos a lanzar son estos

```
4 drwxrwxr-x  2 laura laura     4096 mar 15 09:26 __pycache__
4 -rwxrwxrwx  1 laura laura      124 abr 21 11:01 python.sh
4 -rw-rw-r--  1 laura laura      416 mar  8 21:09 req.txt
4 -rw-rw-r--  1 laura laura      181 mar 30 09:50 scrapper2.py
```

Contenido: python.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/laura/Descargas/scrapper2/venv/bin/activate && python3 /home/laura/Descargas/scrapper2/scrapper.py
```

scrapper2.py

```
service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

Esto, como digo aquí funciona correctamente. ¿Alguno puede ayudarme?

Comment: Me parece que esto no es un error de bash ni de linux, sino tan solo de Python. Igual intentaré responder porque creo que tengo idea que sucede

Comment: Acabo de ver esta publicación en un sitio en inglés donde añade más parámetros a su código para arreglarlo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58997940/selenium-grid-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-unknown-error-chrome-fail

Comment: Quizás ahora que sabemos que tal vez no es un problema con Bash, puedas compartir tu código de python